# Garbage collection clean object with spring bean as property

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, garbage-collection

Hypothetically there is a code

`actionService.processAction(new HelloWorldAction("Hello world", helloWorldRepository))`

Where `helloWorldRepository` is Spring bean.

Will garbage collector some-when clean that `HelloWorldAction` object or because this object have reference to `helloWorldRepository` it will live forever in JVM and its better to use WeakReference if I want to avoid this situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A short-lived object has a reference to a long-lived object. That causes no problem: the short-lived object, when it's not reachable anymore, can be garbage collected. And it should quickly become unreachable if nothing has a reference to it.

There would be a problem if a long-lived object kept references to short-lived objects. Then the short-lived objects wouln't be GCed.

Answer (score 1):

Instance of `HelloWorldAction` is *eligible* for garbage collection when it is totally *unreferenced*. i.e. you don't have any reference to get it back. So, As a rule, when you want to make it eligible for garbage collection, remove all references to it. There shouldn't be any reference pointing to it

Comment: What matters is not the number of references, but the reachability of this object from a root through a chain of references. i.e. graphs of objects can be garbage-collected fine.

Comment: yes, that's it. that is what i have said in my answer as well

Comment: No, that's not what you said. You said to "remove all the references to it". You said: "There shouldn't be any reference pointing to it". That's incorrect.

Comment: I think i have wrongly communicated by saying "There shouldn't be any reference pointing to it". I mean there shouldn't be any way to get it back in the application. Am i making it in the correct sense?

Comment: I indeed think you understand how it's working, but your choice of words makes the reader think that all references to an object must disappear for an object to be eligible to GC. [Reachability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Reachability_of_an_object) is the appropriate term.

Comment: @JBNizet Yeah, right. Thanks for your information. I will make use of Reachability instead of references

Answer (score 1):

An object is not kept alive simply because it holds a reference to some other object (with a different lifetime). It's just the other way around: your `HelloWorldAction` will keep the `helloWorldRepository` object alive, i.e., all objects being referenced by `HelloWorldAction` will live at least as long as the `HelloWorldAction` instance, but if the last reference to the `HelloWorldAction` instance goes out of scope, it becomes eligible for garbage collection, regardless of the references, it itself holds.

Comment: Thanks, I messed up my garbage collection knowledge, I suppose I need to re-read Java specification.